# How do i change the value of ItemHeader.Text in ListView while using LiveBinding

Tags: delphi, listview, header, delphi-10-seattle, livebindings

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I have a ListView that's filled via a RESTclient etc. i get categories from the server that go from 0 to 15 and i want to rename the 0 to Test. I know this is easely solvable by just changing it server side but i want to try and fix this on client side so i learn more about delphi.

The problem mostly is getting the specific value out of an event. i can get the value from OnAssigningValue but its all dumped in variable and i have 2 .Text values linked to the listview so i can't go that way either.

i can't find any solution across the interwebs, any help would be appriciated

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far; post some code.

Comment: livebinding doesn't use code, thats the problem. if i did it in code it'd be easy but i have to do it in livebinding.